# How to make a timer to re-load figures with new values - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, timer, figure

How can I create a timer to refresh my script every minute?

I have figures/graphs in my script which change based on live data that is updated in my script every minute.

I want the show all of the figures, hold for a minute, then run the script again and display the new figures with those updated values. The timer remains indefinitely until the user hits esc/exit command.

I'm aware of `tic, toc and pause` but can't get them to work i.e

```
tic

*script code*

toc

pause
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **timer object**. The timer used for `tic` `toc` (stopwatch timer) is for time measuring and performance evaluation purposes. `pause` also has different usage.

```
Per = 60; % Update period in seconds

tim = timer('Period', Per, 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
    'TimerFcn', 'Update_Script');
```

Supposing that the `Update_Script` is a script that updates all the graphs, (well you need to store the graphic (axes) handles to be able to update them later.)

Then you have to start the timer to run:

```
start(tim)
```

and you can stop it with stop command: `stop(tim)`

See the [timer class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timerclass.html).

Comment: I don't want to stop the timer. I want all of the figures to load then hold for 60 seconds (can I still access my workspace variables this way?), then i want the script to re-run again so that the figures are replaced with the new updates ones. I essentially want to REFRESH my script indefinitely. Can I automate in this way?